# Exclude column from natural join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, natural-join

I currently have the following PostgreSQL DB (picture only contains essential components):
[image: DBVis image]

Basically: 
Each TX has some number of TXINs and some number of TXOUTs and each TXIN consists of a RING of TXOUTs (Monero transactions)

If I join the `ring` table with the `txin` table i use `select * from ring natural join txin` and it uses `inid` for the join. 
Same for `ring` and `txout` except it joins on `outid`.

Both `txin` and `txout` can also be joined with a natural join `tx` to get sensible outputs.

The only thing that (expectedly) does not work is:

```
select * from txout natural join ring natural join txin;
```

Because it then joins `ring(inid) = txin(inid)` and `ring(outid) = txout(outid)` (which is desired) but also `txin(txid) = txout(txid)` which is not desired.

I have a few ideas how to solve this problem:

1. Use explicit joins (makes some queries quite cumbersome in my opinion), e.g. the above would be:  `select * from txout join ring using (outid) join txin using (inid);`
2. Rename one of the two txid columns in either txin or txout and give up on the natural join with tx
3. Use a view of txin/txout that omits txid for these operations

Is there another (better) way? If not - which method would be best practice?
Is my DB-design lacking and the whole problem could be circumvented somehow?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, forget about the `natural join` construction. Specify the join columns!

Comment: This is the bad side effect of a natural join, might happen a lot when you got some DATE columns in your tables. I would never use it ...

Comment: @dnoeth The idea is that your data element names should be consistent and unique throughout your schema, rather than relying on the table name to provide context. As regards the example you give, I've seen this where the designer had mixed audit data (e.g. row creation date) with 'entity' data in the same table, rather than having separate audit tables. Apply these fixes to a broken schema and `NATURAL JOIN` is a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural joins are explicitly defined as joining on all columns with the same name. That's just how it is, it's effectively the same as (if this syntax were valid) `JOIN table USING (*)`. **There is nothing wrong with verbose SQL**. It is far nicer and more maintainable to be extremely clear on your join conditions, and it'll mean if you add a column to these tables in future it won't mess with historical data. In this case I'd suggest joining using explicit syntax, as this makes it clear where the data is coming from:

```
SELECT * 
FROM txout to
INNER JOIN ring r ON (to.outid = r.outid)
INNER JOIN txin ti ON (r.inid = ti.inid)
```

To be clear here. Natural joins are not a maintainable solution, they're great for hacking together a view in a pinch but schemas change, and if you're using a natural join over an explicit join you will run into issues when they do.

I'm not really sure why you've designed your DB how you have, it looks like the data has intentional overlap and could all be put in a single table of `(txid, inid, outid, txhash)` but perhaps I lack complete context.

Comment: If you want to save some typing, an alternative is `... join ring r using (outid)`

Comment: I was going to put that, but I think for someone coming along to this for the first time, stating that you join `ring` for the `outid`s, then from `ring` you join `txin` on the `inid`s is a lot clearer (of course anyone familiar with the schema will know this already, and performance wise the 2 are negligibly similar)

Comment: Thanks. I will go with this. Concerning the single table design: A TX can have many inputs and many outputs and each inputs can also have multiple outputs. I think if I'ld use the single table approach I would have to save txhash multiple times (for each combination of inid and outid) instead of only once.

Comment: "schemas change, and if you're using a natural join over an explicit join you will run into issues when they do" -- only if you've not done your job correctly and failed to code defensively! e.g. provide access to these tables for this set of users via these views/procs only, then test that changes to tables do not break those clients.

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with verbose SQL. It is far nicer and more maintainable" -- opinion presented as fact! How quickly can you verify by eye these two are relationally equivalent?: `SELECT C1, C4, C8, C7, C5, C0, C6, C2, C9, C3 FROM T;` vs `SELECT C6, C1, C9, C4, C8, C3, C0, C2, C5, C7 FROM T;`. How quickly can you verify by eye these two are relationally equivalent?: `SELECT * FROM T;` vs `SELECT * FROM T;`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the simplified Oracle syntax:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ring
  JOIN txout USING(outid)
  JOIN txin  USING(inid)
```